# Oracle SQL Developer "ORA-01722: invalid number"

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting this error "ORA-01722: invalid number" when trying to run my query. I've rewrote the query several times trying to get around the error, but can't seem to do it. It has to be the case statement throwing it off where I am comparing class levels by GPA hours earned. Sure someone has some tips or an answer for my problem! Thanks in advance

```
select distinct 
    initcap(stride_last_name),
    stride_first_name, 
    substr(stride_middle,1,1), 
    case
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),'0') between '0' and '29.9' then 'Freshmen'                   
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),'0') between '30' and '59.9' then 'Sophomore'   
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),'0') between '60' and '89.9' then 'Junior' 
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),'0') >= '90' then 'Senior' 
        else 'Freshmen' 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `gpa_hours_earned` column is numeric, this is because you are comparing the sums with strings, which means the string literals like `'29.9'` are being implicitly converted to numbers, and your session is set up to have a comma as the decimal separator and a period as a group separator. You can change your session NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting, or use explicit conversin that specifies the decimal separator.

But you should not use text literals for numbers. Remove the quotes around all of them:

```
select distinct 
    initcap(stride_last_name),
    stride_first_name, 
    substr(stride_middle,1,1), 
    case
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),0) between 0 and 29.9 then 'Freshmen'                   
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),0) between 30 and 59.9 then 'Sophomore'   
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),0) between 60 and 89.9 then 'Junior' 
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),0) >= 90 then 'Senior' 
        else 'Freshmen' 
    end
```

Since you're actual query must have a group-by clause, you don't need the `distinct`. And you could simplify the case, since it uses short-circuit evaluation:

```
    case
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),0) < 30 then 'Freshmen'                   
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),0) < 60 then 'Sophomore'   
        when nvl(sum(gpa_hours_earned),0) < 90 then 'Junior' 
        else 'Senior'
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it! Unfortunately, after taking your advice it still is throwing that error code at me. I'm unsure what in the world is causing it! I removed the distinct, took out the string literals, and reformatted the case statement as you suggested. Is there a next step you may think I could give a try?

Comment: Is `gpa_hours_earned` actually a number column, or a string? If it's a string it almost certainly shouldn't be, and may contain bad values that can't be converted.

Comment: @GMitchell - if it is a number, can you edit the question to show the whole (original) query, and the table definition, and the complete error message? The error may be coming from something you haven't shown.

Comment: Yes, it is a number column. SHRTGPA_HOURS_EARNED    NOT NULL NUMBER(9,3). The complete error message >>           ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I will post the query give me one sec